# Updating vector by passing by reference in constructor

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to write a piece of code where I am passing the vector by reference through constructor of a class  and updating the vector in the member function of the class. But when I get back to the main function, no update occurs in the vector:

// Header file

```
 class A{
 private:
        std::vector<T> &x;
 public:
        A(std::vector<T>& x_):x(x_) {}
        int func();
 };
```

// Cpp file

```
int A::func() {
     // process done
     T temp;
     x.push_back(temp);
}
```

// Main function

```
int main() {
    std::vector<T> vec;
    A a(vec);
    a.func();
}
```

I have tried changing the vector to be a pointer in the class instead of a reference but the vector doesnt update after the function runs. Any suggestions on what to change in the program?

Comment: Are you getting any compiler errors? Also, can you post the constructor code?

Comment: I am getting no error but the size of the vector is 0 after the function runs. I have nothing in the constructor at all.

Comment: "but the vector doesnt update after the function runs" How do you know? Does the debugger say that? Or did you write some code to check that?

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=fd6bc90b2c3e9d78292a5d44e2e44b13-3b440a87a52fe2ae7c853c82f4c5144f)

Comment: Yeah I checked in the debugger. The size and the capacity of the vector remains zero even after the function runs. In the function, the vector updates properly.

Comment: @shunyo, Don't trust debuggers all too much on that sort of thing.

Comment: @chris, yeah I have been sitting with this for well over a day. Cant seem to find any reason why it shouldnt work.

Comment: Thanks guys. Debugger duped me.

Comment: The code you've posted won't even compile.  If you've got a test version that's similar to what you've posted, post that.
You're using a template style without defining that properly and the A::func isn't returning a value.

Comment: @MichaelH It already compiles and works well. Thanks for the concerns though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>   
#include <vector>  
using namespace std;

class A
{
    std::vector<int> &x;
public:
    A(std::vector<int>& x_):x(x_) {}
    int func();
};

int A::func(){
    int temp=0;
    x.push_back(temp);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> vec;
    A a(vec);
    a.func();
    return 0;
}
```

everything is ok vec changed. I think you have another question or bug that you even dont aware of .

Comment: Its working. The debugger was not updating properly. Thanks for checking though.